# Different behaviour php pthreads in console and in browser

Tags: php, pthreads

I was programming an application using php and pthreads and I noticed that it was't working correctly. In order to isolate the error I reduced the code, and now I have this piece of code, and I've checked that it behaves differently when executes it through the console than trought a web browser, and I can't find why, I'm here for help. The code is:

```
<?php
echo "beforethread<br/>";

class AsyncOperation extends Thread
{
    private $sum;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sum = 5;
    }

    public function run()
    {           
        echo "insidethread<br/>";
    }       
}

$thread = new AsyncOperation();
$thread->start();   
$thread->join();        
?>
```

through console I get:

```
beforethread
insidethread
```

and through a web browser:

```
insidethread
beforethread
```

I can't understand if php executes line by line why through web browser the code doesn't behave correctly. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not write standard output in a web environment from any thread other than the one responding to the request. This is not safe, at least you will experience garbled output and at worst segmentation faults (since you are filling the buffer for stdout from another thread, which is not allowed, zend provides no way to abstract this).

Even at the console, if you want to make sense of your output you should use a mutex when writing to stdout.